# Add stripe in Meteor@1.3

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to add stripe on my client. [the docs say to include it from an external source](https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form#step-1-collecting-credit-card-information).

However, I can't quite find the right way to do this. When I put it in the `head` tag, it gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_iframeBaseUrl' of undefined
```

Then, if I try to use `Stripe.setPublishableKey`, `Stripe` continues to be undefined.

What is the correct way to include stripe?

Comment: Have you tried using [this package](https://atmospherejs.com/mrgalaxy/stripe)?

Answer (score 0):

You should add it via using a Meteor package. Try this one.
https://atmospherejs.com/mrgalaxy/stripe

On your terminal, go to your development folder and type the following command:

```
meteor add mrgalaxy:stripe
```